# Open Excel and pass file password through

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have some excel files that I refresh nightly

I now want to password protect them in order to modify any data from them, but when the script opens the file it prompts for the password,

how do i pass the password with script?

heres what i use(have tried)

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set rootFolder = fs.GetFolder(fs.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName))
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 oExcel.Visible = True
 oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
 oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
 oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

 For Each file in rootFolder.Files
   If inStr(file.type, "Script") = 0 Then
     Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.path)

Dim WSH
Set WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.sleep(25000)
Wsh.SendKeys "?"
Wsh.SendKeys "{ENTER}"  

     oWorkbook.RefreshAll
     oWorkbook.Save
     oWorkbook.Close
     Set oWorkbook = Nothing
  End If
 Next

 oExcel.Quit
set oExcel = nothing
```

any help? i dont really use vbs much(at all)

edit, this code works in opening the file refreshing all, saving then closing, i just dont know how to get it to input the pass word in order to open it in full edit mode

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set rootFolder = fs.GetFolder(fs.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName))
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 oExcel.Visible = True
 oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
 oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
 oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False


 For Each file in rootFolder.Files
   If inStr(file.type, "Script") = 0 Then
     Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.Path)

     oWorkbook.RefreshAll
     oWorkbook.Save
     oWorkbook.Close
     Set oWorkbook = Nothing
  End If
 Next

 oExcel.Quit
set oExcel = nothing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't clear to me but in addition to the advice by @wahwahwah here is the other interpretation:

```
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file.Path, Password:="<myPassword")
```

**Edit**

```
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, Password:="<myPassword")
```

**Edit 2**

Further discussion and clarification identified that this syntax in VBScript seemed to work!

`Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.Path,,,, "mypassword",,,,,,,,,,)` parameters to suit.

[this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.15).aspx) gave the inspiration!

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/…

Comment: it didnt work, getting an error of "expected end of statement"

Comment: @lookslikeanevo - apols, missed out the parentheses, answer edited

Comment: How did you protect your workbook? and can you post your latest code line for opening the file.  If you are using variables in this code line, include the values of these variables.

Comment: using office 2010, using 
the same basic method as this
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/39992-password-protect-excel-only-people-password-can-edit.html

Comment: @lookslikeanevo  Set oWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & file, Password:="barry")  I think this is it, the syntax of 'path & file' rather than 'path.file', or if they are concatenated together 'filepath'

Comment: the code i am using now to open and refresh the files is posted above

Comment: Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.open(file.name)  this works to open , but i cant figure out the password part

Comment: To my earlier question - how did you protect your workbook? - OOPs OK got it

Comment: this is how i am protecting the workbook 

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/39992-password-protect-excel-only-people-password-can-edit.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66296/discussion-between-barryleajo-and-lookslikeanevo).

Comment: @barryleajo Since all of the parameters are optional, there shouldn't be a need to include the trailing commas - in fact it might even cause a syntax error. The call should simply be `Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.Path,,,, "mypassword")`. It is also important to know how the Excel file is protected. If the workbook is password protected then the `Password` parameter should be used. However, if the workbook is only write protected then the `WriteResPassword` parameter should be used.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password" 
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="password"
```

Or in your case:

```
oExcel.Workbooks.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password = "password"
```